# how to move image processing to non-main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, memory-management, camera, preview

My app takes every frame from camera preview in yuv format and compresses to jpeg. it works on API8 but on Android >4 it says that too much work is done on main thread and frames skipped. everything other works but image processing is treated as too expensive. For me its more important then if it freezes UI. can i escalate priority or smth to stop frames skipping? I tried to move processing on other thread but how send yuv images from camera to other thread for processing. i sent byte array with bundle but it eat memory and worked only for a few seconds
here's my code:

```
   public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
                                       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
                                       @Override
                                       public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                                           if (serverActivity.IPAddress != null) {
                                               Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                                               int imageFormat = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
                                               if (imageFormat == ImageFormat.NV21) {
                                                   Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
                                                   //YuvImage appeared only in API8 - Froyo
                                                   YuvImage img = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);

                                                   bytearray = new ByteArrayOutputStream(20000);
                                                   try {
                                                       img.compressToJpeg(rect, 30, bytearray);
                                                       dataimage = bytearray.toByteArray();

                                                       serverActivity.send2thread(dataimage);
                                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }
        );
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch(IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"error setting camera preview: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

onPreviewFrame runs about 15 times per second and if i send data[] to other thread through bundle i get serious memory leaks. i have blur understanding of memory handling when working with threads.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with an AsynkTask
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You have it right that it should be on a separate thread, but there may be a couple of things you could optimize.

1. Make sure you only process one image at a time. Ie, don't process every image you get, only process once the previous task has ended. (I think this might be the issue, since the blocking of the UI thread would prevent you from processing concurrently and seeing the impact on mem and cpu)
2. Recycle any bitmaps you no longer need.
3. Are you sending an actual `android.os.Bundle` to the thread instead of `byte[]`, or was that just phrasing? Either way, I'd expect raw `byte[]` to be faster.
4. Depending on what processing you are doing on your image, it might be worth while to downscale it if quality isn't super important.

Comment: I cant see how I can use asyncTask. I need to send byte[] a dozen times per second to the thread. I used handler and sent bundle. Kevin, thanks for the tip, i don't know how to send byte[] without bundle. i made sure that second image is waiting for current be finished but it didnt solve. I dont know how to recycle bitmaps either.

Comment: `bitmap.recycle();` should be fine, note that you should only do this if you dont need that bitmap anymore. And you could create a custom `Thread ` or `Runnable` class that takes a `byte[]` argument in the constructor, or method parameter, etc.